# Split to ArrayList using pattern matcher in Java

Tags: java

```
String s = "A..?-B^&';(,,,)G56.6C,,,M4788C..,,A1''";
String[] result = s.split("(?=[ABC])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

**Output:**

```
 [A..?-, B^&';(,,,)G56.6, C,,,M4788, C..,,, A1'']
```

Please refer to the The split in the above case. I am trying to separate strings based on `A, B or`C. How can I get the the same split strings into an `ArrayList` using `pattern matcher`? I could not figure out how to group in the below code.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=[ABC])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
   matches.add(m.group());
}
```

Also suppose I have few characters before first occurance of `A, B or C` and I want to combine with first element in `ArrayList`. ,,A..

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Why don't you want to use your first solution?

Comment: Can't you use `String[] result = Pattern.compile("(?=[ABC])").split(s, 0);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[ABC][^ABC]*
```

If I didn't ommit any edge case that should work with the code you provided

For the extra question, you could possibly add `(^[^ABC]*)*` to the beggining, but that makes it slower and look less readable, not to mention it will only work for single-line strings to check. I would recommend just parsing the beggining characters manually, treating it like a special case it is.

Comment: Your answer's much better than mine. +1 and deleting.